NextUI styles not working with Tailwindcss
So my tailwind css works, but various styles that are usually used by NextUI components aren't included in tailwindcss by default, like text-tiny, or bg-default-400 etc
This is my
global.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

tailwind.config.ts
const { nextui } = require('@nextui-org/react');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const config = {
    darkMode: ['class'],
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        './node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    prefix: '',
    theme: {
    },
    plugins: [require('tailwindcss-animate'), nextui()],
} satisfies Config;

export default config;

And I use a component like:
https://nextui.org/docs/components/date-picker
It works fine, but it looks horrible. It does not take most of the styles that aren't present in tailwind css by default.

What to do?
There are various css classes like:
.bg-code-background {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-code-background)/var(--nextui-code-background-opacity,var(--tw-bg-opacity)))
}

.bg-content1 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-content1)/var(--nextui-content1-opacity,var(--tw-bg-opacity)))
}

.bg-content2 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-content2)/var(--nextui-content2-opacity,var(--tw-bg-opacity)))
}

.bg-content2\/50 {
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-content2)/.5)
}

.bg-content3 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-content3)/var(--nextui-content3-opacity,var(--tw-bg-opacity)))
}

.bg-content4 {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: hsl(var(--nextui-content4)/var(--nextui-content4-opacity,var(--tw-bg-opacity)))
}

That are nextui classes but don't come with tailwind css.

Okay so the node modules were happening in a separate folder, but my tailwind was in a separate folder.
